# permutation group and cycle index question regarding peterson graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> A symmetry of graph $X$ is a permutation of the vertices that also happens to be a permutation of the induced edges. In particular, the distances between vertices are preserved by a symmetry. Show that the set of symmetries of $X$ is a permutation group of $\operatorname{V}(X)$. Compute the cycle index of the group for the Petersen graph.

Alright I am super confused. I have no idea how to even start. Can someone point me in the right direction. How do I show that something is a permutation group? How do I compute the cycle index of a graph?

Answer (score 1):

The question of how to compute  the cycle indices of the automorphisms
of the Petersen graph acting on the vertices and edges no doubt admits
a sophisticated  answer from graph theory  in the latter case.

There is however a very simple  way to compute these two cycle indices
that does not  examine all possible permutations of  the ten vertices.
Instead we simply  make use of the fact that  the automorphisms of the
Petersen graph  are obtained  from the action  of the  symmetric group
$S_5$  on  the  two-element  subsets of  the  five-element  set  whose
intersection determines adjacency of two vertices (the subsets are the
vertices and  they are  adjacent if they  are disjoint).  Therefore we
need only iterate  over the $120$ permutations in $S_5$,  let them act
on the vertices/edges,factor the result  into cycles and add the $120$
contributions to obtain the cycle indices.

In the first case we obtain for the vertex cycle index the answer

$$Z(P_v) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{10}}{120}}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{3}+1/
8\,{a_{{2}}}^{4}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/6\,a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{
1}}a_{{6}}a_{{3}}\\+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{2}a_{{2}}+1/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{2}$$

Computing the vertex  colorings with at most $N$ colors  we obtain the
sequence

$$1, 34, 792, 10688, 90005, 533358, 2437848, 9156288, 
\\ 29522961, 84293770,\ldots$$

which points us to  [OEIS A063843](https://oeis.org/A063843). We learn
that what  we have  here is  the cycle index  of the  edge permutation
group of the  complete graph $K_5,$ which is  perfectly correct, since
the edges of that graph correspond  to the two-element subsets and the
action is the action of the symmetric group on the five vertices.

In the second case we obtain for the edge cycle index the answer

$$Z(P_e) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{15}}{120}}+{\frac {5\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}{a_{{1}}}^{
3}}{24}}+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}a_{{2}}a_{{1}}+1/6\,{a_{{3}}}^{5}+1/6
\,a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{3}$$

getting for the colorings

$$1, 396, 123786, 9002912, 254721400, 3920311044, 39571426713,
\\ 293231076608, 1715840171595, 8333541708700,\ldots$$

The Maple code for this  is as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := [seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))];

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_cycleind_petersen_verts :=
proc()
option remember;
local pet_verts, perm, vperm, s;
    pet_verts := convert(choose({seq(k, k=1..5)}, 2), list);

    perm := firstperm(5); s := 0;

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        vperm :=
        subs([seq(q=perm[q], q=1..5)], pet_verts);

        s := s + pet_autom2cycles(pet_verts, vperm);

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    s/120;
end;

pet_cycleind_petersen_edges :=
proc()
option remember;
local pet_verts, vidx1, vidx2, v1, v2, pet_edges, perm, eperm, s;
    pet_verts := convert(choose({seq(k, k=1..5)}, 2), list);

    pet_edges := [];

    for vidx1 to 10 do
        for vidx2 from vidx1+1 to 10 do
            v1 := pet_verts[vidx1]; v2 := pet_verts[vidx2];

            if v1 intersect v2 = {}  then
                pet_edges :=
                [op(pet_edges), {v1, v2}];
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    perm := firstperm(5); s := 0;

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        eperm :=
        subs([seq(q=perm[q], q=1..5)], pet_edges);

        s := s + pet_autom2cycles(pet_edges, eperm);

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    s/120;
end;

P :=
proc(N)
    option remember;
    local idx;

    idx := pet_cycleind_petersen_verts();
    subs([seq(x=N, x in indets(idx))], idx);
end;

Q :=
proc(N)
    option remember;
    local idx;

    idx := pet_cycleind_petersen_edges();
    subs([seq(x=N, x in indets(idx))], idx);
end;
```

**Remark.** The cycle index of the action on the vertices through the action on the edges of $K_5$ of the symmetric group appears through the complement of the Petersen graph.